# Unable to execute updateR command

Tags: r

i have been trying to update R, i used following commands

```r
install.packages("installr")
library(installr)
updateR()
```

after typing this line i get an error saying

> "R code execution error"

what does it signify?
How to resolve above issue?
Thanks

Comment: If you have run the command with in the double quotes, then remove it and run it `install.packages("installr"); library(installr)`

Comment: i tried using without quotes, i am getting following error:
Error in install.packages : 'match' requires vector arguments

Comment: Can you try with the `github` version from [here](https://github.com/talgalili/installr)

Comment: I always find it easier to just download and fresh install the new version of R

Comment: I am trying to understand the error.